# Meaning of $lw=\frac{V}{H}$ in this design optimization example?

Tags: optimization

[Here](http://www.engr.uvic.ca/~mech410/old/2_Lecture_Notes/7_Design%20Optimization-SM.pdf), p.6, an elementary example of design (size) optimization is given.

It's of a tray that has given volume $V$ and height $H$.
The design problem is to select length, $l$, and width, $w$, of the tray.

[image]

So,

given $lwh=V$ and $h=H$,

A "workable design" is $$lw=\frac{V}{H}$$

What is the meaning of $lw$? It's an area of a rectangle, but how does this define the optimal design?

Comment: It is not optimal. Any $l * w$ satisfying the equation are feasible solution. The optimality comes from defining an objective function. As the next slide in your link shows the objective function could be total material volume.

Comment: @skr Aha, so "workable design" is the same thing as "feasible solution".

Comment: I think that's what the author meant.